# WordPress sidebar dropping to the bottom of the page when comments are added

Tags: css, wordpress, css-float, comments, sidebar

Hey I have noticed that when comments are added to my blog page for some reason the right side menu goes to the bottom of the page. I have no clue what could be causing it. the website was built on WordPress and is using the typical WordPress float right expressions for its sidebar. You can see the problem here: http://www.wilhelmcoq.com/welcome-to-my-blog/

Here is what the sidebar us suppose to look like on the blog pages: http://www.wilhelmcoq.com/the-ever-changing-world-of-film-and-video/

does anyone know what i should be doing to fix this issue? I would greatly appreciate your help. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You've got some missing closing `</div>` tags. That's a very common cause of a "drooping" sidebar in WordPress.

See [[Invalid] Markup Validation of   wilhelmcoq.com welcome-to-my-blog  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//www.wilhelmcoq.com/welcome-to-my-blog/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654)

and compare to

[[Invalid] Markup Validation of   wilhelmcoq.com the-ever-changing-world-of-film-and-video  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//www.wilhelmcoq.com/the-ever-changing-world-of-film-and-video/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654).

Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code. Start fixing the code errors and revalidate.